# Can I iterate through the widgets in a databricks notebook?

Tags: python, databricks, azure-databricks, dbutils

Can I iterate through the widgets in a databricks notebook?  Something like this pseudocode?

```py
# NB - not valid
inputs = {widget.name: widget.value for widget in dbutils.widgets}
```

Answer (score 7):

Yes.  You can get all of the widgets returned as a JavaMap.  Then you can convert that to a Python dictionary.

```
%python
my_widgets = dbutils.notebook.entry_point.getCurrentBindings()
{key: my_widgets[key] for key in my_widgets}
```

Note that "entry_point" is not a supported part of the `dbutils` API.
Databricks could change or remove it without notice.

Comment: Excellent. I tried to find a more elegant way to convert the JavaMap to a dict but your solution worked out best. I'd tick your answer as correct if I had enough reputation to do so!

Comment: @MichaelGrazebrook I would just write `dict(dbutils.notebook.entry_point.getCurrentBindings())`. Also: there is no reputation threshold to tick an answer as correct.

Comment: this solution produces an empty dict in our spin of Azure Databricks even despite job parameters being present

Answer (score 0):

i'm not 100% sure but i think so but if not then you might have to manually input the widgets in by them self and not grouped

Comment: I expect they're grouped at some level - but the user has no access.